# Apollo - GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm using **GraphQL** in ui/playground, with the syntax bellow, works pretty well.

```js
    mutation {
      createUnit(unit: {name: "hehehe great!!!"}) {
        id,
        name
      }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

My doubt is, how can I use GraphQL in Apollo Client, I found something like that:

```js
mutation createUnit(unit: {name: String!}) {
       createUnit(unit: {name: "looks great!!!"}) {
                            id,
                            name
                        }
                    }
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the error:

**GraphQLError**: Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name "unit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the type `Unit` and added  the `createUnit` type as a mutation in the resolvers

```
module.exports.Mutation = {
    createUnit
}
```

to use it in the graphql playground you just have to specify the variables you are going to use in the mutation like this

```
mutation($unit: Unit){
  createUnit(unit: $unit){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

and in the variables add :

```
{
  "unit": {
    name: "looks great!!!"
  }
}
```